# How do I export an email to PDF from Outlook?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-outlook-2010, print-to-pdf, xps

I found this link on the Office website that explains how print a PDF in all apps except Outlook

https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/Save-as-PDF-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110

**Question**

How can I export a message, in Outlook 2010, and have the output result in a PDF file?

Comment: This question will probably be closed for being off-topic but before it does you should look into the **CutePDF** writer which is basically a print driver which converts whatever you "print" to it into a PDF file. Processing will take between 1 and infinity seconds depending on how complex and big the PDF is going to be.

Comment: Personally, I use PDFCreator because it is also free and gives me more options on what to do with the PDF. For example, I can save it in a specific directory, give it an automated name, or even e-mail the PDF to someone.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm not convinced that he is looking for a software rec. He said how can I do it, not what software do I need ...

Comment: @DavidPostill good call, I retracted that comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

#### Save a received message as a PDF or XPS file

> **You can’t directly save a message as a PDF file in Outlook 2010**.
>
> Workaround: However, you can use the information in [Save a received message as
> a Microsoft Word document](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Save-a-message-4821bcd4-7687-4d6d-a486-b89a291a56e2#__save_a_received) to save your message in Word, and then save the new document as a PDF file.

Source [Save a message](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Save-a-message-4821bcd4-7687-4d6d-a486-b89a291a56e2)

Note that the above workaround contains a large number of steps. The other options below include alternatives with far fewer steps.

#### Other Options

Some other options can be found at [Saving emails as pdf-files](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/643):

> - **Adobe Acrobat** comes with a dedicated Outlook add-in which lets you convert a single message or selected messages to a pdf-file, append an already existing pdf-file or convert an entire folder at once.
> - **The Save As PDF add-in** from Sperry Software provides similar functionality as the Adobe Acrobat add-in for Outlook but is probably more affordable for most as it is built specifically for this task.
> - **Save As PDF macro** - Another option is to use a VBA macro which uses Word’s capabilities to
>   save documents in the pdf-format.
>   As the VBA code and installation instructions are provided for free,
>   it offers a cost effective alternative if you only occasionally need
>   to save messages in the pdf-format or when you are in an environment
>   where you cannot install software yourself.
> - **PDF printers** are virtual printers which you can select from your list of printers, but instead of printing to paper it produces a pdf-file. These can of course be used in any application which offers a Print function and not just Outlook.
>   While many of them come for free or at a small price, the downside of (most of) these solutions is that they will not maintain any hyperlinks in their output.

Source [Saving emails as pdf-files](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/643)

Comment: -1 Too many steps. PDF Printer (like CutePDF suggested above) is the faster way to go.

Comment: @sunk818 My **other options** include alternatives with far fewer steps. The VBA macro for example could be a single hotkey ...

Comment: If that is your first answer, I will not downvote next time. If you edit your answer, I will remove downvote if I am allowed.

Comment: @sunk818 I just edited to include the other options. I was still working on the question when you downvoted... :/